# What are all the dictation commands in iOS? (iOS 10)

Tags: ios, voice-dictation, text-to-speech

iOS (10) has a speech-recognition-based dictation feature. You press a little microphone button, start talking, and it transcribes your speech into text. Commands I currently know:

- "new paragraph"
- "comma"
- "period"
- "hyphen"
- "dash"
- "colon"
- "semicolon"
- "open/closed bracket"
- "open/closed curly brace"
- "open/closed parenthesis"

However, I do not know voice commands for:

- backspace/delete
- undo/redo
- cycle between alternate options for a word

Please help.

Also, if possible, please let me know how to:

- prevent dictation mode from automatically turning off
- convert pre-recorded audio to text using speech recognition

Comment: Hi. Please put the answers (and the missing items) in an answer - then we can edit the question to be a question - what are the commands for editing that Siri supports for dictation mode. Then people can edit in any missing pieces of answers. Having one large answer will help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

One command that isn't on the list yet:

• "quote" will give you a space then "
• "end quote" will give you a " then space

In other words, say quote at the beginning of a quote and the following text will follow the "like this with no space, and saying end quote will put the quote marks right after the word like this" with no space before the quote. Saying quote again at the end will put a space before it like "this and put it in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comprehensive list of [Dictation commands for Siri](https://www.siriuserguide.com/siri-dictation-guide).

Unfortunately, it doesn't have the ones you asked for, but it has many other useful ones.